# Ubuntu 13.10 ssh Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 last week.
Since, I have troubles with ssh.

When I try to ssh on a server I have :

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to daenerys [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA
debug1: Host 'daenerys' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mart_q/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mart_q/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried a lot of things but finally I don't know what to do...

Somebody know a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a problem during the upgrade.
All my keys were simply deleted.
So I had no access to the server.
If I had been alone on the server, I would have been in an horrible situation...